# Which case can occured invoke-rc.d will be failed but service won't?

Tags: ubuntu, service, debian, deb

I'm developing binary debian package for my application server. Consequently I need to develop postinst and prerm script for it. I should stop the service before install new package in prerm. I find I can't use

```
service myservice stop
```

in prerm and I should use invoke-rc.d instead of it as follow

```
invoke-rc.d myservice stop
```

This commond is always failed by this :

```
Invoke-rc.d: initscript myservice, action "stop" failed
```

when I want to install deb package. I tested it by start too and I got the same error for start action.

Strangely, the service (`myservice`) works normally when I use `sudo service myservice start/stop` without any problem or failure.

Can anyone explain why `invoke-rc.d` command isn't working but `service` command is working?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without any information on the nature of the script, but the main differences between running under `invoke-rc.d` and `service` are that

1. `invoke-rc.d` tries to check whether the service is supposed to be run, given the current runlevel and any system initscript policy (`/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d`), whereas `service` just does what you tell it; and
2. `service` clears out most environment variables and sets the working directory to /, in an effort to make the execution environment as reproducible/predictable as it can. `invoke-rc.d` does not.

So you should probably look at how your current environment or working directory or runlevel might be affecting the initscript. Try running it directly (`/etc/init.d/myservice stop`), and try running it with some shell debugging parameters on (e.g., bash's `-x` option: `bash -x /etc/init.d/myservice stop`).